# add sequence no column according to another column in the table

Tags: mysql

I have the following table

table 1

```
id      stubs   
373      1  
390      4  
392      3  
392      3  
392      3
```

How to create a table2  from table1, Creating the sequence number according to the stubs and id

table 2

```
id      stubs   sequenceno
373        1    1
390        4    1
390        4    2
390        4    3
390        4    4
392        3    1
392        3    2
392        3    3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I use a helper table (in this case dates from my db) which contains a lot of ids in sequential order with no gaps then I can select the distinct id and stubs and join to dates to get the sequence numbers

```
drop table if exists t;
create table t
(id  int,    stubs  int);
insert into t values 
(373   ,   1),  
(390   ,   4),  
(392   ,   3),  
(392   ,   3),  
(392   ,   3);

select s.*,d.id from
(
select distinct id,stubs from t
) s
join dates d on d.id <= s.stubs;

+------+-------+----+
| id   | stubs | id |
+------+-------+----+
|  373 |     1 |  1 |
|  390 |     4 |  1 |
|  390 |     4 |  2 |
|  390 |     4 |  3 |
|  390 |     4 |  4 |
|  392 |     3 |  1 |
|  392 |     3 |  2 |
|  392 |     3 |  3 |
+------+-------+----+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe your answers can be found here.
You can use existing MySQL functions to do that for you.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_row-number